# Is it acceptable to copy other user's common, moderation-related comments?

Tags: discussion

There are several comments, such as "this is Linux but not Ubuntu, ask on Unix SE," "This is Windows, ask on SuperUser," "this release has reached EOL," "this is Ubuntu-based but not an official flavour," etc that appear commonly on this site. I've noticed several users repeatedly use the same comments for these, such as guiverc's one for questions about 14.04:

> Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
> https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

And, again guiverc's, comment for version numbers:

> Ubuntu 18?   Do you mean Ubuntu Core 18? or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ? or something else?  The *year* format release, are different products to the more common *year.month* products; the *year* products are *snap* only so everything is containerized, thus impacting configs.  Please specify your release, as there is no Ubuntu 18.

(haven't seen that one re-used, but still applicable)

Is it ok to copy these comments (and of course other ones by other users, guiverc's were just the two most recent ones I saw) and use them on different posts?

Comment: I see no reason why not.

Answer (score 6):

In the strictest sense, *any* copying should be done with attribution. All the content is under CC-BY-SA... But I personally wouldn't expect somebody to give a moderation comment of mine attribution.

Use your own judgement. If it's short, helpful to the site, bang on.
If you're concerned it's a significant amount of content, give it some attribution (though that might be gnarly).

There used to be a scripted repository of automatic comments for dealing with common we-need-more-information comments, with a user script for adding them. I'm not sure if it still exists.

Comment: It's [no longer maintained](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments), unfortunately, but it may still work. I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth, and a little shameless self-publicising of the 3D Printing SE site, we maintain a list of common moderating/review comments, for everyone to use. Some have been taken from other SE sites, where I had seen them being used frequently, and some are the auto-review comments from other SE sites.

Each comment is displayed as it would be seen (in blockquote format), but to use them it is best to copy the `code formatted` examples, under the "Copy and Paste" logo: **C&P ⎘**. This is because they contain the shorthand links, which don't travel well when copied from the blockquote formatted examples.

Feel free to take a look and use or copy them.

You can find them here, [Do we have Standardised Comments?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/303/4762).

Comment: This looks smart, but let's pay attention that no-one confuses this to a OneTrueWay© of commenting that _has to be used_ from then on. Something that makes things easier is welcome, but something that might be used to impose more conformity in commenting would be a disaster.